# Create DataDog dashboard for all hosts from a template for a single host

Tags: datadog

Not sure if there are any pro DataDog users on here, but I'm hoping.

I've created a template DataDog dashboard template that captures the memory usage of a host by docker container.

The "hostname" appears in 5 or so places:

```
{
  "viz": "timeseries",
  "status": "done",
  "requests": [
    {
      "q": "max:docker.mem.rss{host:are-P-swarmB-swarm-node-1} by {container_name}",
      "aggregator": "avg",
      "conditional_formats": [],
      "type": "area",
      "style": {
        "palette": "dog_classic"
      }
    },
    {
      "q": "max:system.mem.total{host:are-P-swarmB-swarm-node-1}",
      "conditional_formats": [],
      "type": "line",
      "style": {
        "palette": "warm",
        "type": "dashed",
        "width": "normal"
      }
    },
    {
      "q": "max:system.mem.total{host:are-P-swarmB-swarm-node-1} * 0.8",
      "conditional_formats": [],
      "type": "line",
      "style": {
        "palette": "orange",
        "type": "dashed",
        "width": "normal"
      }
    },
    {
      "q": "max:system.mem.total{host:are-P-swarmB-swarm-node-1} - max:system.mem.usable{host:are-P-swarmB-swarm-node-1}",
      "conditional_formats": [],
      "type": "line",
      "style": {
        "palette": "orange",
        "type": "dotted",
        "width": "thin"
      }
    }
  ],
  "autoscale": true,
  "yaxis": {
    "includeZero": false
  }
}
```

I'm trying to set up a dashboard right now that displays this template for each of my 20 or so hosts, but it's a painful process of cloning the chart and editing the host name in all 5 places. Whenever I make a change to the template, I have to painfully paste the changes into each host chart and change the hostname in applicable places.

Is there a way I can set up this template (perhaps with a variable in place of the host name) and have a dashboard automatically create a chart for each host from this template? Failing that, is there a way this can be scripted?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, seems to me what you want is actually Datadog's Dashboard template variables feature? That way you'll be able to set just one dashboard and easily switch between containers/hosts/etc. You can find more info on that here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/templating/

Comment: Nah, my dashboard for a single host is quite small (a single chart) - I want to monitor all hosts simultaneously rather than have a variable I have to change manually to see each host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *could* use the Datadog API to script the creation of 20 unique dashboards that all share the same content, but with different hosts. This is the part of the API docs that would help (with examples!) [for Timeboards](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#timeboards), and this one [for Screenboards](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#screenboards).

That said, I'd personally find 20 dashboards a bit cluttered / unwieldy in my own Datadog account. Instead, if it was me, I'd try to (A) find clever uses of dashboard template variables (on e.g, cluster tags, host tags, etc.), or (B) group out by each host tag and apply [the "top()" function](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204972439-There-are-too-many-lines-on-my-graph-can-I-only-display-the-most-important-ones-) in some way so that I'd be able to see just the most extreme-value hosts. But that's certainly up to you :)

Comment: Thanks. I've already begun efforts on a script, but the `top` function was not one I've played with - that will be useful.